# Can ffmpeg copy g729 audio stream?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming

I'd like to send an RTP stream of `g729` audio data using `ffmpeg`. I have an existing file of `g729` audio and would like to wrap it with RTP headers and send it over the network. Something like this:

```bsh
$ ffmpeg -re -i encoded_audio.g729 -acodec copy -f rtp rtp://<address>:<port>
```

This fails with the message:

```
[rtp @ 0x55f389dea040] Unsupported codec g729
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

I realize that `ffmpeg` [decodes but doesn't encode g729](https://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#Audio-Codecs), but I thought that the point of the `copy` codec was that the encode/decode process was [entirely skipped](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy).

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Muxing in rtp not yet supported by ffmpeg, but allowed by the spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3555#section-4.1.9. Open a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org, if you like.

Comment: @Gyan thanks! Submitted a ticket [here](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8038#ticket)